# 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'applyInPandas' for Pandas udf. Why am I unable to implement applyInPandas for the Grouped Data?

Tags: pyspark, pyarrow

[Code and error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI2yr.png)

Link referred:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html.

I am trying to perform pandas_udf in pyspark.
Pyspark version of mine : 2.4.4
Pyarrow version of mine : 8.0.0

Comment: In the documentation link it says **"New in version 3.0.0."**. `applyInPandas` is not available in Spark 2.4.4

Comment: Is there any alternative in Pyspark 2.4.x ?